# Android Notification not workng

Tags: android, notifications

i have the following code. Problem is, when i click on the notification bar (when app launched i see the *Text inside: By Firstdroid.com* text, but nothing else, even if i click on the bar.

```
  NotificationManager mNotManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String MyText = "Text inside: By Firstdroid.com";
    Notification mNotification = new Notification(
           R.drawable.icon,                // An Icon to display
           MyText,                         // the text to display in the ticker
           System.currentTimeMillis()       ); // the time for the notification
    mNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    String MyNotifyTitle = "Firstdroid Rocks!!!";
    String MyNotifiyText  = "Firstdroid: our forum at www.firstdroid.com";
    Intent MyIntent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), HelloAndroid2.class );

    MyIntent.putExtra("extendedTitle", MyNotifyTitle);
    MyIntent.putExtra("extendedText" , MyNotifiyText);
    PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,MyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(   getApplicationContext(),
            MyNotifyTitle,
            MyNotifiyText,
            StartIntent);

    /* Sent Notification to notification bar */
    mNotManager.notify(  SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID , mNotification );
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are getting at. Could you provide some more details?

Comment: I solved it. There was no problem, i just didn't know that i had had to pull the notification down instead of clicking the green notepad-like button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this to close this question.

Copied from my comment before:
*I solved it. There was no problem, i just didn't know that i had had to pull the notification down instead of clicking the green notepad-like button*